# Grid areas in navigation bar pushed horizontally

Tags: html, css

I tried to add the changes I've made to a web page for the navigation bar, but the layout is messed up. For some reason, the columns have all been moved over by 1 fraction, and the menu burger "buns" are now out of place. Here is some of the code for the navigation elements:

HTML Code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="design.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Comfortaa&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="item logo">
    <h3><a class="myName" href="/index.html">BALLOONS</a></h3>
   </div>
   <div class="item links">
    <ul class="navigation">
     <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">About</a>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#">Maps</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Tours</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="item menu">
    <div class="menu-btn">
     <div id="middle" class="btn-mid"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="response.js"></script>
   </div>
 <div class="item content"></div>
<div class="item footer">
 <div>
 <br><br>
 <ul class="nav_footer">
  <li><a href="/#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="/#">About</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/#">Maps</a></li>
  <li><a href="/#">Tours</a></li>
  <li><a href="/#">Contact</a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS Code

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
}

.logo {
  grid-area: logo;
  display: flex;
  grid-row: span 1;
  grid-column: span 2;
  margin: 2px;
  background-color: black;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.myName {
  font-family: "Comfortaa";
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.myName:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.links {
  grid-area: links;
  grid-column: span 5;
  grid-row: span 1;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 2px;
  background-color: black;
}

.navigation {
  display: flex;
  direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 0; //By default, padding is set
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 80%; //Adds more spacing
}

.navigation a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navigation a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.navigation li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu {
  grid-area: menu;
  grid-column: span 1;
  grid-row: span 1;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 2px;
  background-color: black;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu-btn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.btn-mid {
  position: relative;
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.btn-mid::before,
.btn-mid::after {
  position: absolute;
  /*Necessary for 3 bars*/
  content: '';
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.btn-mid::before {
  transform: translateY(-300%);
}

.btn-mid::after {
  transform: translateY(300%);
}


/*BUTTON ANIMATION*/

.menu-btn.open .btn-mid {
  transform: translateX(-175%);
  background: transparent;
}

.menu-btn.open .btn-mid::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(125%, -1050%);
}

.menu-btn.open .btn-mid::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(125%, 1050%);
}


/*END*/
.content {
 grid-area: content;
 grid-column: span 8;
 grid-row: span 3;
 padding-top: 15%;
 background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkpSw.jpg");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 25vh;
}

.footer {
 grid-area: footer;
 grid-column: span 8;
 grid-row: span 1;
 padding-top: 15%;
}

h1 {
 font-family: "Comfortaa";
 text-align: center;
}

h3, h4, p, label {
 font-family: "Comfortaa";
}

.navigation {
 padding: 5%;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: black;
 display: flex;
 direction: row;
 justify-content: space-around;
 font-family: "Comfortaa";
}


@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .links {
    display: none;
  }
  .logo {
    grid-column: span 7;
    grid-row: span 1;
  }
  .navigation a {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 601px) {
  .navigation li {
    font-family: "Comfortaa";
  }
  .navigation a {
    color: white;
  }
}

div {
 text-align: center;
}

.nav_footer {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-align: center;
}

.nav_footer li {
 display: inline;
 font-family: "Comfortaa";
}

.nav_footer a {
 color: black;
}

ul {
 list-style-type: none;
}

li {
 font-family: "Comfortaa";
}
```

But aside from navigation, everything else displays fine, and the animation works as expected. I've included two screenshots.

The first is from a mobile view:
[image]

The second is from a desktop view:
[image]

I entered my code in codepen, and while the menu burger is still messed up, all of the areas fit in the same row like they're supposed to. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any chance you can create a [mcve] in a [runnable snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) in the question?  I moved your code into a snippet and was unable to recreate the issue, which leads me to believe that perhaps the issue lies outside the code you've included here.

Comment: @bds why your using grid, you can use flex instead of display grid.

Comment: I edited the code, so it should be reproducible now.

Comment: I dropped the edited code into a stack snippet and it still looked fine on my machine (Win 10, Chrome).  Is this only being reproduced in a specific browser?  Would you like me to update your question to put your code into a stack snippet so you can see if it still reproduces on your end?

Comment: When I ran the code from a mobile view and on safari and chrome, it looked messed up. I ran the code on codepen, and it turned out fine. So maybe not, I’ll try retyping my code to see if I can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display:flex` instead of `display:grid`. Just add this lines to your **CSS**.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  background:black;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
```

Comment: I'm using display grid to account for size changes from mobile to desktop. And I don't like the layout using flex, it turned out pretty bad on my end.

Comment: @bds ok if you want to use grid check this link "https://coder-coder.com/responsive-navigation-bar-flexbox-vs-css-grid/"  for more details.